# What is the best approach regarding .cfg files for the LaTeX graphics bundle?

Tags: graphics, color, best-practices

The manual for the 'graphics' LaTeX bundle includes instructions for setting up the right conditions for the use of colour and the inclusion of graphics in documents.

For example, on page 2, it says

> You should to set up a site default for these options, for the driver
>   that you normally use. Suppose that you wish for the color package to
>   always default to use specials for the PostScript driver, dvipsone. In
>   that case create a file color.cfg containing the line:
>
> ```
> \ExecuteOptions{dvipsone}
> ```
>
> Normally you will want an identical file
>   graphics.cfg to set a similar default for the graphics packages.

I therefore have `color.cfg` and `graphics.cfg` set up in the personal TEXMF tree.

This is something of a pain, however. If I need to compile cleanly, I put `TEXMFHOME=/non-existent-directory` precisely so that these configuration files are *not* loaded. In this case, the standard TeX Live versions will be picked up.

So I could, I think, just drop these files from my home directory altogether. However, they are useful for some purposes e.g. for additions to the standard configuration.

What is the best way to handle this? Is there a way of including the standard configuration files from within the personalised ones? Clearly I could `\input` them by specifying a full path, but I'm not sure whether that's the right thing to do here.

Comment: I'd just not have the local ones, it makes a hidden dependency that makes your documents non-portable.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle To be honest, I don't worry about portability. Whatever I send elsewhere has to be converted to Word anyway. If I knew even one person who'd take `.tex`, things would be different ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote that a long time ago, before texlive, before tetex probably. The model for the initial releases of latex2e (and graphics) was that individual users would be fetching source files of individual directories from ctan and building a tex setup themselves. (And that the core distribution wouldn't have a `cfg` file so you'd have to write your own if you wanted one at all.)

These days the `graphics.cfg` file (and `color.cfg`) is really an integral part of the tex distribution (whether that is miktex or texlive or something else) and the behaviour of the standard one is just assumed. (Witness how many answers here tell people to avoid specifying driver options to the package so an appropriate driver option will be chosen).

So, it is possible to have a local version, but it's possible to have a local copy of `graphics.sty` or even `latex.ltx` but I would treat these the same way, and only make such modified copies in very special circumstances, and ignore the advice that the `.cfg` file should be written to fit local needs.

Comment: Thanks! What about `color.cfg`? Right now, I guess I'm doing this in some other way, having disabled my copy of this. But it would be useful to be able to define custom colours so they are available whenever colour is used.

Comment: @cfr  same applies really. (The standard color and graphics config are the same really, just detecting pdftex or luatex etc)

Comment: OK. Thanks. That's a shame, but so it goes.

Comment: @cfr Joseph has suggested in chat that an answer from a package author saying to ignore the manual might be a hint that the manual needs updating. I'll see what I can do.